# Activate and deactivate an account

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am working on a project where admin adds all user registration details and creates the account for user. The user uses that account until the user works for that admin. If the user leaves that admin, then admin deactivates the account instead of deleting the account. He deactivates because in future if same employee come back then he would just reactivate the account.

I store all user data in database and now able to add account, edit account, delete account. But instead of deleting I want to deactivate so that in future I can reactivate again as above mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a flag column in your user registration table, and check every time if a user is active user or not and take appropriate actions accordingly.

Here is an example (with some assumptions as you haven't shared your code):-

Assuming, you have user registration table named `users` that contains 4 fields.

`users(id, name, email, password)`

Now, add one more column to it say `state`, so updated table structure looks somewhat like this.

`users(id, name, email, password, state)`

when user tries to login, you might be querying like this,

`Select count(*) from users where email = <email_of_user> AND password = <pass_of_user>;`

Change it to this;

`Select count(*) from users where email = <email_of_user> AND password = <pass_of_user> AND state = 'ACTIVE';
 // you can use any value to denote active/inactive user.`

and if your admin deletes an account, don't actually fire a `delete` query to database, just update the state of that user as 'INACTIVE'.

eg:

`UPDATE users SET state = 'INACTIVE' where email = <email_of_user>;`

Hope this clears every point you need or at least gives you an idea to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is that delete account will actually in database update specific column as IS_ACTIVE, this column will be A for Active and N for Not Active for example.

In your queries of select/view and update always check for IS_ACTIVE equals A value.

1. add account will create with IS_ACTIVE=A
2. edit account will update only records with IS_ACTIVE=A
3. delete account will update only records with IS_ACTIVE=A to  IS_ACTIVE=N

That way also you will never need to delete records.

Comment: seems it might work. Can you elaborate each phase in very detail?

Comment: add details for each action

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solution is to add a field ex: **Enabled** in the database.

...then you can adjust your application logic accordingly.

Maybe some other fields would be useful as LastDeleteDate, or DeletedBy... Possibilities are endless.